# If X is a set with cardinality n, how many distinct r-collections of X are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm currently reading through *Introductory Discrete Mathematics* by V.K. Balakrishnan and came across the following theorem:

If $X$ is a set of cardinality $n$, then the number of $r$-collections from $X$ is $\binom{r + n - 1}{n - 1}$, where $r$ is any positive integer.

To me, it seems like the number of such $r$-collections ought to be $\dfrac{n^r}{r!}$ since each collection will have $r$ elements and for each of those $r$ elements there are $n$ choices. But, obviously, $n^r$ would be an overestimation considering order does not matter and since each collection of $r$ elements could be permuted in $r!$ ways, we divide by $r!$.

It seems that either I have made a mistake (very likely), he author has made a mistake (much less likely), or maybe my solution and the author's are actually equivalent. If anyone could shed some light on this I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the example $n=3$, $r=2$. Then

- There are six $2$-sets from $X$.

But

- Your formula gives ${n^r\over r!}={9\over 2}$, which isn't even an integer.

I think if you examine this case, you'll see what's going on.

Comment: You are not allowing duplicates, but OP clearly is

Comment: @RossMillikan I've edited to include duplicates. However, note that this is still the right example for the OP to look at - their formula doesn't even given an integer, which is clearly a sign that something is wrong!

Comment: @RossMillikan is correct. These $r$-collections could have duplicates. In general it is certainly possible that $r > n$. However, Noah is clearly correct that there is significant issue that my solution may not even yield an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is assuming that order matters.

For example say we want to calculate the number of size $2$ subsets from $\{1,2,3\}$. Your method assumes we pick a number, say $1$ and then pick another number, say $2$. You have counted this outcome in you answer. However you have also counted the case that you pick $2$ first and then $1$ afterwards. So here you have double counted the subset $\{1,2\}$. Hope this makes sense - probability can be really subtle!

As for how to count it and get the correct answer (which is the one the author gave), have you heard of stars and bars? Look it up and it should be a lot clearer.

Comment: I thought that by dividing by $r!$ I was accounting for this issue since a given r-collection would have $r!$ possible orderings, all of which are the same collection?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem with the OP's formula. (Which is not to say that there *is* no problem - see my answer . . .)

Comment: @Budge:  but some collections have a different number of orders.  The one of all $1$'s has only one order, so should not be divided by $r!$

Comment: @RossMillikan Ahhhh yeah that makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it's as Ross says. If a number is chosen twice, then the order changes. In my example $\{1,1\}$ only has $1$ order not $2!$ (despite it containing $2$ elements).